# Implementing Samsung Galaxy Note S-Pen AirView previews in app

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Is there a way to implement the Samsung S-Pen AirView previews, like in the Samsung Note's stock email app or in mini-windows menu bar buttons, in my own app? Is there an API? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you probably want to start by checking out the [S Pen Sdk](http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk) with the related documents and tutorials.